# Alignment of simd_packed vector in Swift (vs Metal Shader language)

Tags: ios, swift, metal, simd-library

I have trouble understanding something about simd_packed vectors in the simd module in Swift. I use the example of float4, I hope someone can help.

My understanding is that `simd_float4` is a `typealias` of `SIMD4< Float>`, and `MemoryLayout<SIMD4< Float>>.alignment = 16` (bytes), hence `MemoryLayout<simd_float4>.alignment = 16`. Makes sense.

But the following I do not understand: `simd_packed_float4` is also a `typealias` of `SIMD4<Float>`. And so `MemoryLayout<simd_packed_float4>.alignment = 16`.

What is the point of the "packed" in `simd_packed_float4`, then? Where is the "relaxed alignment" that the documentation talks about?

In the Metal Shader Language Specification (Version 2.4) (
https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)
in Table 2.4 (p.28), it says the alignment of `packed_float4` is 4 (which is also the alignment of the scalar type, float), so this IS a "relaxed alignment" (as compared to the 16). That makes sense on its own, but how do I reconcile this to the above (`simd_packed_float4` is typealias of `SIMD4<Float>` and `MemoryLayout<simd_packed_float4> = 16`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think it's impossible to achieve relaxed alignment like this with a packed type in Swift. I think Swift compiler just can't bring the alignment attributes to actual Swift interface.

I think this makes `simd_packed_float4` useless in Swift.

I have made a playground to check this, and using it as it's intended doesn't work.

```
import simd

MemoryLayout<simd_float4>.stride
MemoryLayout<simd_packed_float4>.alignment

let capacity = 8
let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: capacity)

for i in 0..<capacity {
    buffer[i] = Float(i)
}

let rawBuffer = UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer.init(buffer)

let readAligned = rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * 4, as: simd_packed_float4.self)

print(readAligned)

let readUnaligned = rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * 2, as: simd_packed_float4.self)

print(readUnaligned)
```

Which will output

```
SIMD4<Float>(4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0)
Swift/UnsafeRawPointer.swift:900: Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer
```

If you do need to load or put unaligned `simd_float4` vectors into buffers, I would suggest just making an extension that does this component-wise, so all the alignments work out, kinda like this

```
extension UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer {
    func loadFloat4(fromByteOffset offset: Int) -> simd_float4 {
        let x = rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: offset + MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * 0, as: Float.self)
        let y = rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: offset + MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * 1, as: Float.self)
        let z = rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: offset + MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * 2, as: Float.self)
        let w = rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: offset + MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * 3, as: Float.self)

        return simd_float4(x, y, z, w)
    }
}

let readUnaligned2 = rawBuffer.loadFloat4(fromByteOffset: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * 2)
print(readUnaligned2)
```

Or you can even make it generic

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and example code!

Comment: No problem. In my code I use generic `load2`, and `load4` functions that will read 2 or 4 things of the same type and create a simd vector from them.

Comment: I will follow your example. Thank you again!